# How to preserve jQuery.ajax.data object when using closure compiler?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

When using closure compiler with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, jQuery.ajax.data object is changed:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax.php",
  data: {
     act : "some"
  },
  success : function(data){}
});
```

jQuery.ajax.data object is converted to `{L : "some"}`

I can use quotes, like `'act' : "some"`, but I want this to work without quotes. 
In my externs file there is:

`/** @type {Object.<string,*>} */
     jQuery.ajax.data;`
But this doesn't work. Closure compiler version 1043

Comment: You need the quotes to tell Closure not to mangle the property name.  This is a requirement.  You cannot get it to work without quotes.

Comment: Your extern file is also not correct.  `jQuery.ajax.data` means the `data` property under `jQuery.ajax`.  There is no `data` property under `jQuery.ajax` (which is a function).  `data` is a property of an object passed to `jQuery.ajax` as an argument.  You are "externing" the wrong thing.

Comment: However, if you do: `var foo = {}; foo.act = null;` in your extern file, Closure will no longer rename any property called "act" (or any variable called "foo", which you don't care) on **ALL** objects, *including* in your object hash passed to the "data" property.  However, beware that ALL properties called "act" will not be renamed, even when you want them to!

Comment: Same question, same answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823811/prevent-google-closure-compiler-from-renaming-settings-objects/7825886#7825886

Answer (score 0):

Try the externs with something like :

```
var jQuery = {};
jQuery.ajax = {
    data: '' 
}
```

This will not rename 'jQuery.ajax' and 'jQuery.ajax.data'